# What does "^." and "!" mean in apache config?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have following rewrite rule:

```
   # Rewriting without query parameters to avoid cache overloading
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(en|fr)/search-results.html
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !referrerPage=automotive-home
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/search-results.html$ $1/search-results.html? [NC]
```

As I understand

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(en|fr)/search-results.html
```

will return true if `{REQUEST_URL}` will like:

```
https://www.trololo.com/en/search-results.html

https://www.trololo.com/fr/search-results.html
```

Please explain the last two `RewriteCond`s:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !referrerPage=automotive-home
```

1. `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.`
   Does this mean that `QUERY_STRING` is not blank
2. `%{QUERY_STRING} !referrerPage=automotive-home`
   Does this mean that `QUERY_STRING` doesn't contain `referrerPage=automotive-home` ?

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/intro.html

Comment: I don't see anything about **!**

Comment: Look closer: `In mod_rewrite the ! character can be used before a regular expression to negate it.`

Comment: Does **^.**  means that **QUERY_STRING** should begin from any symbol? wtf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex `^.` means match *any one character*`.  The`^` itself represents the start of the string, and is often not really needed for generic expressions like this; it could have been omitted

The `.` matches *any one character*... So in this context, it means the query string must have at least 1 character; if the query string is empty, the condition will not be met.

```
# If the requested query string is *not empty, having at least one character*
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.

# ...and the query string does not contain "referrerPage=automotive-home"
# It doesn't need to be the complete expression because it is not anchored
# with ^ at the start and $ at the end, so this pattern will match
# if it appears anywhere in the query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !referrerPage=automotive-home

# If the above 2 conditions were met, the next `RewriteRule` will be processed.
# This rewrite rule's purpose is to erase the query string. Since it terminates in 
# ? without a [QSA] flag, any existing query string will be removed
RewriteRule ^(.*)/search-results.html$ $1/search-results.html? [NC]
```

In this case, the first `RewriteCond` could just be expressed without the `^`

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
```

As mentioned in the comments, the `!` negates the subsequent expression. This, along with the anchors and the `.` character are documented in [the `mod_rewrite` regex vocabulary.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/intro.html#regexvocab)

Finally, beginning with Apache 2.4, there is [a `[QSD]` ("query string discard") flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsd) which achieves the same thing as ending the target URI with `?` to erase the query string.

Comment: what does it mean **QSA** ?

Comment: what does it mean **$1** ?

Comment: **With the [QSA] flag, a request for /pages/123?one=two will be mapped to /page.php?page=123&one=two. Without the [QSA] flag, that same request will be mapped to /page.php?page=123 - that is, the existing query string will be discarded.** I didn; understand where  **pages** if we use **$1**

Comment: That assumes a `RewriteRule ^pages/(\d+) page.php?page=$1`  If you replace the query string, the old one will not be appended without [QSA], but if you don't add anything it would automatically be appended.

Answer (score 1):

- RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^. ==> the requested query string is not empty, having at least one character
- %{QUERY_STRING} !referrerPage=automotive-home ==> the query string does not contain "referrerPage=automotive-home"